# Performance Hit on Android App

Tags: android, android-fragments

Folks,

I have a home fragment with a map & actionbar which loads a series of default markers, also I have a search fragment that I can call and return results from a viewpager into a recyclerView as a list and on this results fragment I can see my results in the map or as a list, however if I click to see my items on a map they load just fine but if I click on any menu item in the action bar it takes over 30 seconds to load the sub menus items in my action bar items.

Is it possible that my emulator is slow,I am running a Nexus 5 4.4.4 emulator on Genymotion and it has never given me any performance issues before
thanks

Some code

Home Fragment onCreateView

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
     final String TAG_MAP=getActivity().getClass().toString();
    session=new UserSessionManager(getContext());
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    //Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000L,500.0f, this);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
        setMarkerCircle();
    } else {            
        onProviderDisabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);



    }
    return view;

}
```

OnStart Code:

```
 public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    showItemsinMap(lat,lng);
}
```

OpenItemsinMap (in Results List Fragment) code:

```
private void openAllMap(Bundle allProductsBundle)
{


    //Create a JsonObject to iterate and get the values I need to show on map (ie. Lat and Lng)


    Bundle objBundle=new Bundle();
    objBundle.putString("OBJECTS",jObjAllPs.toString());


    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_slide_in_top, R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom);
    Fragment FragmentMap = new Fragment_Home();
    //Send Bundle to Next Fragment
    FragmentMap.setArguments(objBundle);
    transaction.replace(R.id.container,FragmentMap);
    //transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentProductSearchResults);
    transaction.addToBackStack("PRODUCT_RESULTS_FRAGMENT");

    transaction.commit();


}
```

When I get back to the MapFragment (which was loaded in the Home Fragment) and I click on actionbar to do any action it gets very very slow. Note: If I click on "View Results on Map" button (on my Result List Fragment) the code calls the OnCreateView again (from Home Fragment), maybe I am hogging memory due to having 2 map objects created since I transitioned from Home Fragment to other fragments without destroying the map object create initially???

Comment: Seeing code would be helpful

Comment: What does your search fragment do? Is it calling a remote API that scans a full database worth of results? That surely will cause a performance hit

Comment: actually the search returns a list of 10 items very fast, I think the issue is that I call a New Fragment every time I switch from List View to Map View to see my results. The result API call is called only once and I move between fragments with a Bundle of a JsonObject with the results values